# c# selenium keys are held for too long

Tags: c#, selenium

The bot holds the ctrl and v for too long and it pastes the message twice.
How can I make it hold the 2 keys for less time?

```
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(head).SendKeys("v").Perform();
action.KeyUp(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(head).SendKeys("v").Perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(head).SendKeys("v").Perform();
action.KeyUp(Keys.Control).Perform();
```

and if that doesn't give the required behaviour see section "What are the different methods provided by the Actions class for Keyboard Events?" here [Selenium QA](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/keyboard-events-in-selenium/).